# Django ORM - INNER JOIN to a GROUP BY subquery on the same table using PostgreSQL

Tags: django

I've got a table that looks something like this (I've omitted some columns):

| ID | Key_ID | Project_ID | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123456 | a |
| 2 | 1 | 123456 | b |
| 3 | 2 | 123456 | c |
| 4 | 2 | 123456 | d |
| 5 | 3 | 654321 | e |
| 6 | 3 | 654321 | f |
| 7 | 4 | 654321 | g |
| 8 | 4 | 654321 | h |

Using Django ORM, I would need to get the equivalent of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(ID) AS max_ID FROM table
    GROUP BY Key_ID
    WHERE Proeject_ID = 123456
  ) AS sub_query
  ON t.ID = sub_query.max_ID
```

I've tried some `aggregate` and `annotate` combinations but I don't seem to be able to achieve the `GROUP BY` in the subquery. If I could do that I could then try to use a `.filter(id__in=<subuery_result>` so effectively use a `SELECT ... WHERE ID IN <subquery_result` although the `INNER JOIN` would be ideal as the subquery result could be quite large.

**UPDATE:**

The database I use is PostgreSQL and the accepted answer only works with this.

This is the actual model:

```
class SystemKey(models.Model):
    # The ID (primary key) is handled by Django.

    key_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        help_text="Unique key ID from System."
    )

    project = models.ForeignKey(
        "core.SystemProject",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        help_text="System project that this key belongs to.",
    )

    # There are a whole bunch of other properties here

    record_created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        help_text="Date & time when this record was added in the database.",
    )

    record_updated = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        help_text="Date & time when this record was updated in the database.",
    )
```

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: I need to run this on one model (not join across different models). The model has the fields that I've shown, as well a few others that are not relevant to the query but which I'll need once I get the result, hence the `SELECT *`. For ilustration purposes, let's just assume it's called Table.

Comment: but `project_id`, this is a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Yes, it is a `Foreign Key` but I need to get the results one project at a time, so I can write something like `Table.objects.filter(project_id=123456).etc...`. The project ID I'm actually getting from a different system to use in this filter.

Comment: @ovimunt if you use PostgreSQL your query could become as simple as calls to `order_by` and `distinct` (no join). In other cases no it is not possible to (easily without digging deep into the ORM) make arbitrary joins.

Comment: Yes, I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: @ovimunt in that case your can write a query like `queryset.order_by('Key_ID', '-ID').distinct('Key_ID')`, if you would add your model I would add that as an answer.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I've added the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make subsequent calls to `order_by` and `distinct` while passing fields to `distinct` to effectively achieve what you want, with the single caveat being this is only possible for PostgreSQL:

```
SystemKey.objects.filter(project_id=123456).order_by('key_id', '-id').distinct('key_id')
```

Basically here we select entries having distinct `key_id` and since we ordered by `id` in descending order we get only the entries with max id for each `key_id`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and see how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ‘raw()’ through model.objects.raw().

What about

```
Model.objects.filter(projectid=123456).latest(Max_ID)
```

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to avoid, unless it's the only option.

Comment: `latest` will just give one result for the whole `QuerySet`, whereas I need the latest row per each group of key IDs.